# I need to develop a plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have to develop a plugin in WordPress. I have written the code of what i needed in that plugin. But how to wrap that code into a plugin. Need help.

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a plugin, all you need to do is create a folder and then create a single file with one line of content. Navigate to the `wp-content/plugins` folder, and create a new folder named **myplugin**. Inside this new folder, create a file named **myplugin.php**. Open the file in a text editor, and paste the following information in it:

```
<?php
   /*
   Plugin Name: MyPlugin
   Plugin URI: http://example.com
   description: A plugin to create awesomeness and spread joy
   Version: 1.2
   Author: Navnish Bhardwaj
   Author URI: http://example.com
   License: GPL2
   */
?>
```

Of all this information, only the plugin’s name is required. But if you intend to distribute your plugin, you should add as much data as possible.

With that out of the way, you can go into the back end to activate your plugin. That’s all there is to it!